# problema para hacer galeria de imagenes con la librería de owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy tratando de hacer una Galeria con owl carousel pero no me crea bien la web.

Este es mi ejemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
       $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed : 300,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            singleItem:true,
            // Navigation
            navigationText : ["Anterior","Siguiente"],
            rewindNav : true,
            scrollPerPage : true,
            //Pagination
            pagination : true,
            paginationNumbers : false
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>galowl</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
<div id="owl-slider" class="owl-slider">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i0.fiuxy.com/da3512ac064d0df844b8c11a9228be4213c27765?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexophase.com%2Fimages%2Fmisc%2FPlayStationConsole_bkg-transparent.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://media.aws.alkosto.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6/small_image/280x/4275c8e8146210f1c7867d9f605120ed/1/_/1_27.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/pxffWV2cRa9BRTkeK7hqVdYd-fo=/830x467/2017/02/23/5bf20b56-a1a7-4587-868f-f9f848dbc7bf/nintendo-switch-console-4923.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CYpJofogtVs/UeQvGG__8OI/AAAAAAAAFWM/mOPkjXJpsOg/s1600/famicom.png" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona exactamente? ¿Puedes indicar de forma más clara dónde está el error? ¿Sólo tiene que aparecer titular 1 y los otros deben estar ocultos?

Comment: Incluye el fichero *.css. Para que todos los `div`te aparezcan alineadas en una fila deben tener la propiedad `display: inline-block;` O en su defecto incluye la parte del fichero css del framework que estás usando.

Comment: Además Beinat, pusiste el `div` con clase "owl-slider" en vez de Id, y en el codigo lo referencias con "#". En jquery el "#" significa `id` y "." es para clases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo de carrusel con la libreria Slick, sacado el codigo de su pagina web: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```js
$('.your-class').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i0.fiuxy.com/da3512ac064d0df844b8c11a9228be4213c27765?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexophase.com%2Fimages%2Fmisc%2FPlayStationConsole_bkg-transparent.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://media.aws.alkosto.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6/small_image/280x/4275c8e8146210f1c7867d9f605120ed/1/_/1_27.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/pxffWV2cRa9BRTkeK7hqVdYd-fo=/830x467/2017/02/23/5bf20b56-a1a7-4587-868f-f9f848dbc7bf/nintendo-switch-console-4923.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/world-of-media/images/0/08/Family_Computer.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140119223513" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="title">Titular 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @lois6b prueba el responsive de la imagen con estos atributos del tipo imagen o bien le creas una clase y se lo aplicas a la imagen: `img { height: auto; max-width: 100%; }`. La imagen debe estar además en un `div`con clase `container`.

Comment: @David gracias por la sugerencia. con la nueva libreria que uso no hace falta ^^

Comment: Como podría hacer para que quede como la galeria de imagenes de esta pagina?  
[logitravel.com/hoteles/expo-barcelona-1051453.html]

Comment: @beinat ni idea. veo que te cerraron por duplicado, voy a votar para reabrirte esa pregunta. y por favor, deja de editar mi respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: lo acabo de dar como valida, a ver si se habre la pregunta..